# getNamedQuery is returning null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a NamedQuery that, for some reason, is returning null. The syntax seems valid:

```
 @NamedQuery(name="Usuario.userLogin", query = "SELECT u.email, u.senha FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :mail AND u.senha = :senha")
```

The password is hashed using MD5. (Useless for security reasons, but not the point of the question).

This is where the hash is verified and then redirect if the login is valid.

```
  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    String mail = request.getParameter("mail");        
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");
    try {
        senha = ControllerUsuario.criptografa(senha);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CadastroUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Usuario user = ControllerUsuario.getSenha(mail, senha);
    if (user != null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        pw.println("Tipo: " + user.getEmail());
        session.setAttribute("mail", user.getEmail());
        session.setAttribute("tipo_usr", user.getTipo_usr());
        session.setAttribute("usr", user.getUsuario());
        session.setAttribute("logado", 1);
      //  response.sendRedirect("index");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("cadastro-falha.html");
    } 
}
```

This is where the user and password is verified. However, this always is returning null attributes.

```
  public static Usuario getSenha(String mail, String senha) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    try {
        session = sf.openSession();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Usuario.userLogin");
        query.setParameter("mail", mail);
        query.setParameter("senha", senha);
        user = (Usuario) query.uniqueResult();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Grave:   java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.coursera.Model.Usuario
at org.coursera.Controller.ControllerUsuario.getSenha(ControllerUsuario.java:67)
at org.coursera.View.Login.processRequest(Login.java:32)
at org.coursera.View.Login.doPost(Login.java:72)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[Index]: Servlet.service() for servlet Index threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.coursera.View.Index.processRequest(Index.java:50)
at org.coursera.View.Index.doGet(Index.java:103)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace? what attributes are null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the reason but in hibernate you dont need '*Select*' keyword. So:

```
 @NamedQuery(name="Usuario.userLogin", query = "u.email, u.senha FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :mail AND u.senha = :senha"
```

And also you would like to see exception :

```
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); <--here logging or etc..
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

EDIT:
 Also you are trying to select fields of Usuario here :

```
u.email, u.senha FROM Usuario u
```

But trying to cast this fields into Usuario object:

```
user = (Usuario) query.uniqueResult();
```

in this case you can also get rid of fields:
 @NamedQuery(name="Usuario.userLogin", query = "FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :mail AND u.senha = :senha"

Comment: Hibernate threw exception `ERROR:   line 1:1: unexpected token: u`

Comment: its better you update your question and add exception there

Comment: You do need the select keyword if you are going to specify only some parts of the result to be returned (`u.email, u.senha`).

Comment: @athosbr99 glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to be in your cast `user = (Usuario) query.uniqueResult();`, since you're selecting two items and not a whole `Usuario`.

Just add `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch clause and you'll see the real reason.